# Tensorflow Object Detection Multi-GPU parameters

Tags: tensorflow, parameters, object-detection

For most models in order to use 3 GPUs I can set `--num_clones=3 --ps_tasks=1` when running training. However, for a few models this doesn't work. There's other parameters like `worker_replicas, num_ps_tasks, num_replicas`.

Would someone please explain the meaning behind these parameters and give an example of how I could set them to use a single machine with N GPUs?

By the way the model I'm trying to run is `ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config`